# Is there a way to strip field set and description from [submission:values] in the emails tab?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a very long form. I would like to use the simple *[submission:values]* token in the email, but I'm hoping there is a way to add something that will leave out all the extraneous information like field set labels and descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

my English is not very good but you can follow these steps to solve your problem.

1 -add email,
2 -select custom body and the values you want to include,
3 -exclude empty values and boxes that are not checked,

you can personalize even better by writing your text and adding the value you want.

for example: "yourText": [webform_submission:values:Element_key]

I hope I have helped you and excuse me for my bad English

[image]